# Date Time format method for standard time (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, format

Its my method to get created date from DB to show in a proper format

```
function showDateTime($student_id, $datetime)
   {

    $time_zone_app = DB::table('students')->where('id', $student_id_id)->value('time_zone');
    $zone_data = explode(':', $time_zone_app);

    $time_zone['hours']   = $zone_data[0];
    $time_zone['minutes'] = $zone_data[1];

    $carbon = new Carbon\Carbon();
    $carbon->setDateTime(2012, 9, 25, 10, 26, 11);
    $carbon->addHours($time_zone_data[0]);
    $carbon->addHours($time_zone_data[1]);

    $datetime = $carbon->toFormattedDateString();
    return $datetime;

}
```

Above I have hard code time because i am not getting time as i want 
if i echo $carbon below `$carbon = new Carbon\Carbon();` It gives me time as

```
2016-9-25 07:04:02
```

I want to convert this time to format `2016, 9, 25, 7, 4, 02` as

(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds)
and then want to pass it to setDateTime method above

Please help how can i do

Comment: According  to the docs of carbon there's a `format` function. Eg. `$carbon->format("Y, m, d, H, i, s")`

Comment: i tried to found but there is nothing to format as above i asked

Comment: Whats there inside `datetime`, can you specify the value & its type

Comment: @ccKep can you share link please

Comment: [Carbon Docs on Formatting](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)

Comment: i use this method $carbon->format("Y, m, d, H, i, s") it giving result as 2016-12-27 07:18:37 but i want as (2012, 9, 25, 10, 26, 11)

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;


$now = Carbon::now();

$now->format('Y, m, d, H, i, s');
```

You can also try following formats.

```
$now->format('d-m-y H:i:s');

$now->format('d.m.y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

Format it the way you want.

```
$carbon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
$carbon->format('Y, m, d, H, i, s')
```

Comment: its not working when i pass $carbon to setDateTime it gives an error 

Missing argument 2 for Carbon\Carbon::setDateTime()

Comment: setDateTime works fine for me which I copied from your question. Did you tried updating your carbon library? Or maybe you are missing something somewhere else.

Comment: Why would you pass `$carbon` to `setDateTime` ? `setDateTime` is a function of `$carbon`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert [carban](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) date formate like:

```
$datetime = '2016-9-25 07:04:02';    
$newdate = Carbon::parse($datetime)->format('Y, m, d, H, i, s');
```

This will produce output like:

```
//output
2016, 09, 25, 07, 04, 02
```

You can test this thing from [here](http://phpio.net/tools/carbon).

Comment: I try to do it as   `$newdate = Carbon::parse($datetime)->format('Y, m, d, H, i, s');
    $carbon->setDateTime($newdate);` its giving error 
Missing argument 2 for Carbon\Carbon::setDateTime(),

Comment: its close to solution now problem i am facing is that how to pass this time which i am getting in this format as format('Y, m, d, H, i, s'); to setDateTime method .yon can review it above from my question

Comment: You can try `list($year, $month, $date, $hrs, $min, $sec) = explode(', ', $newdate);` to extract all values and use that. I'm not sure how it worth, try it with own risk.

Answer (score 1):

```
First Option:
If you want to use laravel format then you can flow it
 {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($quotes->created_at)->format('d-m-Y i') }}
```

See this url 
    https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-format-a-carbon-date-inside-blade

```
Second Option: 
if you want to custom format then you can use it.
Use example :
 echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35');
echo time_elapsed_string('@1367367755'); # timestamp input
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', true);
Input can be any supported date and time format.
```

Output :
    4 months ago
    4 months, 2 weeks, 3 days, 1 hour, 49 minutes, 15 seconds ago
    Function :

```
 function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
        $now = new DateTime;
        $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
        $diff = $now->diff($ago);

        $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
        $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

        $string = array(
            'y' => 'year',
            'm' => 'month',
            'w' => 'week',
            'd' => 'day',
            'h' => 'hour',
            'i' => 'minute',
            's' => 'second',
        );
        foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
            if ($diff->$k) {
                $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
            } else {
                unset($string[$k]);
            }
        }    
        if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
        return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
    }
```